# Mysql Db Layout for Movie Information from java

Tags: java, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to write a java-based movie database program. It recursively searches a given list of folders, retrieves information about the movie files within, and allows you to search for movies using tags/actors/file resolution/etc, and will show a cover thumbnail of the movie and screenshots.

The program as I have it now stores information (atm only filename/size) in arraylists, and generates a html page with the thumbnails. I would like to use a mysql database instead so it will persistently store the movie information and doesn't have to search through all the folders every time.

I can use a "Media" object for each movie to store all this info, but I'm not sure of the best way to store this in a database. I don't want to just serialize the Media objects because then I would have to iterate through the whole db to search, which would be slow. I assume I need to use mysql queries to search.

I have only a less than basic knowledge of database design although I do have an idea how to use jdbc to create/access a mysql database once I have decided on a layout.

Can anyone give me some pointers on what I need to learn and where to learn it in order to decide how to lay out/index and link the tables for my movie database?

Here's my current Media object:

```
public class Media {

    File file_location;
    String filename;
    Date date;
    int hres;
    int vres;
    boolean has_tbn;
    File tbnloc;
    boolean has_ss;
    File ssloc;
    int length;
    String[] actors;
    String[] tags;
    boolean HD;
    long filesize;
    String md5;
```

Comment: It would be nice if people who downvoted would write a comment suggesting what they would like clarified or what was stupid about the question I asked in good faith. Bad karma for you!

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, I assume you already know how to setup/create a MySQL database, so I won't bother with that.

First, you will need to make a table for your media. Start designing a column that can store each object in your Media class with the appropriate data type, as well as set a primary key, which should be unique. This is preferably a separate id number. Also be sure to specify which columns cannot be null or blank, to avoid accidentally writing incomplete data.

However, I also see you have arrays for actors and tags. As a designer, I would prefer for these to be in separate tables, with another table joining them to the main media table for a many-to-many relationship. You could also make it simpler and just set it as a long string with a separator that you will parse and place into the array.

You may want to reconsider saving a file directly into MySQL as well. I prefer just saving the file location and keeping the actual file as is.

I think you should also take a look at the sample database the current version of MySQL has, called [Sakila](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/index.html), which should also be available for install when you install the latest version of MySQL. It's a database for a video store, and thus has well-designed tables for storing film data and all its related factors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll check out Sakila. I wasn't intending to store the actual movie file in the database, that would be crazy! Just a media file location link.

Comment: Haha, I didn't really assume you were going to store an actual movie. I just saw that you had File datatypes and assumed that one of them may contain an actual file, like a screenshot.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I actually didn't think of putting the screenshots into the db either, currently they're just saved as the same filename as the movie with a .tbn extension. They are just links to the file's location in the class file.